# Kivy add_widget does not show new widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add widgets in a Scrollview placed inside a Screen, but I can not understand what is the problem with the code. The code does not give me any error but it does not show the new widget. When the button "add" is pressed, the funcion add() is called but it does not work.

Here there is the code.py

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass    
class Screen1(Screen):
    pass    
class Screen2(Screen):
    pass    
class ClassAllScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass        
class ClassApp(App):    
    def add(self):   
        self.s2 = Screen2()    
        layout = GridLayout(cols=3)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Test'))
        layout.add_widget(TextInput())
        layout.add_widget(CheckBox())     
        self.s2.ids.widget_list.add_widget(layout)
    def build(self):
        self.root = ClassAllScreen()
        return self.root    
kv = Builder.load_file("main2.kv")    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClassApp().run()
```

and the kv file:

```
<Screen1>:    
    GridLayout:
        cols:1        
<Screen2>:    
    GridLayout:    
        cols:1    
        Button:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            text: 'add'
            on_release:
                app.add()    
        ScrollView:    
            size_hint: 1, 1
            do_scroll_x: False
            padding: 20
            spacing: 20    
            GridLayout:   
                id: widget_list
                cols: 1
                spacing: 5    
                GridLayout:
                    rows: 1        
<ScreenManagement>:    
    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'    
<ClassAllScreen>:    
    orientation:'vertical'    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1    
        GridLayout:    
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.12    
            Button:    
                text: "Screen 2"
                    on_release:
                    app.root.ids.screenmanager.transition.direction = 'right'
                    app.root.ids.screenmanager.current='screen2'    
            Button:    
                text: "Screen 1"    
                on_release:
                    app.root.ids.screenmanager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    app.root.ids.screenmanager.current='screen1'    
        ScreenManagement:
            id:screenmanager
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `add()` method, the code:

```
self.s2 = Screen2()
```

is creating a new instance of `Screen2`. Then you are adding widgets to that new instance. However, that new instance is not part of your GUI. What you want is to add the widgets to the `Screen2` instance that is in your GUI. To do that, replace the above code with:

```
self.s2 = self.root.ids.screenmanager.get_screen('screen2')
```

This code gets the `ScreenManager` using its `id`, and then uses `get_screen()` to the the `Screen2` instance.